# iPhone compass woefully inaccurate

Tags: iphone, gps

Not sure when this started, but heading/compass on 2 iPhones (6 and X) is way off for some reason. Magnetic north  is off by 10-40°, depending on how much moving around I do. True north mostly works, but is also off. There is a difference between the two devices of 5-30°  No electromagnetic interference that I can trace nearby.    What could possibly cause this? The GPS signal on the X is also quite bad and takes very long to lock. I did the sim eject-reboot routine, to no effect

Comment: Consider that it could be a hardware defect. I had that with one phone with once - confirmed by Apple and replaced under warranty.

Comment: Are you saying that both iPhones have bad compass readings?  There's several questions here already about inaccurate compass readings, have you tried any of those answers?

Comment: @jksoegaard on both devices? Hoping it’s unlikely, as sometimes the readings are accurate.

Comment: @fsb yep, both are off, but off by a different amount. I tried recalibration, that didn’t seem to help. In addition to that, I am not seeing the expected gps accuracy increase from the quad constellation chip in the X

Comment: @4004 At the time, I understood it as the two devices having different readings - meaning that one of them would be inaccurate.